# Magento2 : How to Create custom theme in PWA Studio

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, custom-theme, pwa, venia

Anyone have any idea about how to Create custom theme in PWA Studio Magento2 ?

Comment: If you have installed and run the pwa then please answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256439/how-to-run-pwa-in-magento-2-3

Comment: You need to create a project based on the magento pwa studio. Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/299021/27183 for further information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created new theme under **pwa-studio/packages/custom** and copy all files from **venia-concept**

**I have changed in below files :**

Added below code in `pwa-studio/lerna.json`

```
"packages/custom"
```

and

Added below code in `pwa-studio/package.json`

```
"watch:custom": "cd packages/custom && npm run -s watch; cd - >/dev/null"
```

Comment: How can i see my custom theme at frontend, when run pwa buildind command get aebsite url it shows me venia theme at frontend please help me on this ...

Answer (score 5):

We are creating a custom theme based on pwa-studio with this repo https://github.com/Jordaneisenburger/fallback-studio