# How to run PWA in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, pwa

After Installing and setup the Magento 2.3 how to run PWA in local ?

Comment: Which OS currently you are using? It works only on Ubuntu

Comment: I did post an answer to this yesterday at [PWA install with Magento 2.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256320/pwa-setup-in-magento-2-3-0/256330#256330)

Comment: Ubantu - Linux Mint

Comment: I am looking for - how to use the urls for PWA and how to check GraphQl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento2 : How to Create custom theme in PWA Studio](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256351/magento2-how-to-create-custom-theme-in-pwa-studio)

Comment: @YannMartel please check my ans.

Comment: You need to create a project based on the magento pwa studio. Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/299021/27183 for further information

Answer (score 5):

I have installed PWA in Magento2.3 in Ubuntu OS

**Prerequisites**

[NodeJS >=10.14.1 LTS](https://nodejs.org/en/)

[Node Package Manager (NPM)](https://www.npmjs.com/)

**Step 1**
Setup Fresh [Magento 2.3](https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/#choosing-the-magento-23-backend)

**Step 2**
Clone the [PWA Studio](https://github.com/magento-research/pwa-studio) repository into your development environment.

**Step 3**
Install PWA Studio dependencies

```
npm install
```

**Step 4** 
Specify the Magento backend server

Under the packages/venia-concept directory, copy .env.dist into a new .env file:

***Example command:***

```
cp packages/venia-concept/.env.dist packages/venia-concept/.env
```

*NOTE:* In **.env** file do not change anything

**Step 5**
Add Venia Sample data

Create `packages/venia-concept/deployVeniaSampleData.sh` and copy paste below code

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
    add_composer_repository () {
    name=$1
    type=$2
    url=$3
    echo "adding composer repository ${url}"
    ${composer} config ${composerParams} repositories.${name} ${type} ${url}
}

add_venia_sample_data_repository () {
    name=$1
    add_composer_repository ${name} github "${githubBaseUrl}/${name}.git"
}

execute_install () {
  composer='/usr/bin/env composer'
  composerParams='--no-interaction --ansi'
  moduleVendor='magento'
  moduleList=(
      module-catalog-sample-data-venia
      module-configurable-sample-data-venia
      module-customer-sample-data-venia
      module-sales-sample-data-venia
      module-tax-sample-data-venia
      sample-data-media-venia
  )
  githubBaseUrl='git@github.com:PMET-public'

  cd $install_path

  for moduleName in "${moduleList[@]}"
  do
     add_venia_sample_data_repository ${moduleName}
  done

  ${composer} require ${composerParams} $(printf "${moduleVendor}/%s:dev-master@dev " "${moduleList[@]}")
}


skip_interactive=0
install_path=./

while test $# -gt 0; do
  case "$1" in
    --help)
              echo "Magento 2 Venia Sample data script install."
              echo "if no options are passed, it will start interactive mode and ask for your Magento absolute path"
              echo ""
              echo "Usage:"
              echo "  deployVeniaSampleData.sh [options]"
              echo "Options:"
              echo "  --help    Displays this!"
              echo "  --yes     Skip interactive mode and installs data"
              echo "  --path    your Magento 2 absolute path, otherwise will install in current directory."
              echo ""

              exit 0
              ;;
--yes)        skip_interactive=1
              shift
              ;;
--path*)      if test $# -gt 0; then
                install_path=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//g'`
              fi
              shift
              ;;
*)            break
              ;;
  esac

done


if [ "$skip_interactive" == 1 ]; then
  echo "Skipping interactive mode.."
  echo "Install path ${install_path}"
  execute_install
else
  echo "Please specify absolute path to your Magento 2 instance"
  read -p 'Magento root folder: ' install_path

  echo "Sample data will be installed there."
  echo ""
  read -p "Are you sure you want to continue? [y/n]" yn

  case $yn in
    y )
      execute_install
      ;;
    n )
      echo "Sample Data instalation failed."
      exit 0
      ;;
    * )
      echo "Exiting..."
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac

fi
```

**Step 6** Start the server

Before you run the server, generate build artifacts for Venia using the following command in the project root directory:

```
npm run build
```

**Run the server**

Use any of the following commands from the project root directory to start the server:

```
npm run watch:venia
```

Comment: Hi @yann-martel If this answer helps you please accept.

Comment: I'm getting error : lerna ERR! npm run build -s exited 1 in '@magento/pwa-buildpack'
lerna ERR! npm run build -s stdout:

Comment: @KaushalSuthar checkout package-lock.json, package.json then run npm install, then run npm run build, then run  npm run watch:venia

Comment: @hweb87 can you please tell me in windows also

Comment: @hweb87 do we need to install the complete pwa studio ? Can't we just install the required magento npm modules for our theme ?

Comment: @santhoshnsscoe  you should in stall npm modules in PWA studio not in magento

Comment: @hweb87 as per https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/technologies/storefront-architecture/buildtime/#repository-organization "---Early adopters of PWA Studio have cloned the pwa-studio repository and made direct customizations to the Venia concept source. This can lead to conflicts when updating to the latest version of the codebase. The preferred approach is to add PWA Studio tools and libraries as dependencies in a project.---". I am not getting how to start a project adding dependencies on the magento pwa studio tools....

Comment: @hweb87 i got the answer from https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/299021/27183 .... yarn create @magento/pwa   inside the magento pwa studio will create a new project to work for.

Answer (score 1):

First of all install Node js latest version using following command

```
- curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -
- sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
- sudo apt install npm
```

Now go to Magento Root directory :

```
- cd var/www/html/pwa-magento/
```

Download PWA clone directory and install npm into this directory using following commands

```
- git clone https://github.com/magento-research/pwa-studio.git
- cd pwa-studio/
- sudo npm install
- cp packages/venia-concept/.env.dist packages/venia-concept/.env
- sudo npm run build
```

==========================================

if npx not found error PWA magento 2.3

```
- sudo npm i -g npx
```

---

if error found like this : Cannot find module 'envalid' then run following command

```
- sudo npm install i envalid
- sudo npm install envalid
```

---

if error like this then run following command : lerna ERR! npm run build -s exited 1 in '@magento/venia-concept'

```
- sudo npm restart
- sudo npm run stage:venia
- sudo npm cache clean -f
- sudo npm install -g n
- sudo n stable / sudo n latest (depends on version)
```

===========================================

```
- sudo npm i @magento/pwa-buildpack
- sudo npm i @magento/upward-js
- sudo npm i @magento/venia-concept

- sudo npm run build
- sudo npm run watch:venia
- sudo npm run watch:all
```