# Magento2 PWA Studio install in windows

Tags: magento2.3, pwa-studio

*Magento2*: How to **install PWA Studio in windows**.Can you explain in step by step process. What are libraries and tools we need ? I need to install it in windows?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/256909/62614

Comment: @AshishViradiya  i need for windows

Answer (score 1):

Now clone pwa-studio repository

```
git clone https://github.com/magento-research/pwa-studio.git
```

You have to clone this repository in magento root directory ex: `/var/www/html/magento`

You will see the pwa-studio directory in `/var/www/html/magento`.
Enter into this directoy:

```
cd pwa-studio/
```

Specify the Magento backend server in `.env` file. you can see the `.env.dist` file in
`/var/www/html/magento/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/` direcoty. If you are not
able see, enable show hidden files. Now create .env file from this `env.dist`

```
cp packages/venia-concept/.env.dist packages/venia-concept/.env
```

Open this `.env` file and find `MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL`. Here configure your
local Magento 2 instance, my case it is:

```
MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="https://magento2-pwa.com/"
```

Find the `deployVeniaSampleData.sh` file in
`/var/www/html/mage0/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/` directory. and copy this
file in your Magento root directory. Now it must look like
`/var/www/html/magento/deployVeniaSampleData.sh` Now run:

```
bash deployVeniaSampleData.sh
```

> After successful installation run:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Reference: https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-3-pwa-studio-setup/

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Is this for windows?

Comment: No. This is not for windows. Its worth pointing out at this stage that magento 2 is not compatible with windows. You can get it working but there are a lot more steps to follow.

Comment: @DominicXigen Can you please suggests steps in windows..bcoz am using windows machine

Comment: @Muhammad...can you explain in windows

Comment: Please read the question carefully

Comment: @Nadh probably best to use a virtual machine or dual boot